# Rails - unsuccessful edit in modal on index site

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I have a list of group and I want to edit a single group name via modal. I use edit.js.erb file and bootstrap modal.

There are two cases, both wrong.

First:
Using "remote: true" in Partial and link_to(in single row file)
Then modal is displaying, but after SAVE button clicked always is rendering again and never close. (I don't know why)

Second:
Delete remote:true from partial.
Then modal is displaying, I can even save the changes. But when I type wrong name (blank or too long), line "render 'edit'" from Controller crash. (error: "Missing template groups/edit, application/edit...". I think rails doesn't know about edit.js.erb then, but how to repair it?

Have you got any ideas about this situation ?

Controller

```
def edit
 @group = current_user.groups.find_by(id: params[:id])
 respond_to do |format|
   format.js # actually means: if the client ask for js -> return file.js
 end
end

def update
 @group = current_user.groups.find_by(id: params[:id])
 if @group.update_attributes(group_params)
  flash[:success] = "Nazwa grupy została zmieniona"
  redirect_to groups_path
 else
   render 'edit'
 end
end
```

Partial for displaying form_for in modal

```
<%= form_for(@group, remote: true) do |f| %>
<div>
    <%= render 'shared/error2_messages', object: f.object%>
    <p>
        <%= f.label :name, "Nazwa" %>
        <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control'%>
    </p>
</div>
<%= f.submit yield(:button_name), class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

edit.js.erb file

```
<% provide(:button_name, 'Zapisz zmiany') %>
$('.modal-title').html("Edytuj nazwę grupy");
$('.modal-body').html("<%= escape_javascript( render partial: 'layouts/group_data_form', locals: {group: @group} ) %>");
$('#myModal').modal();
```

Single row in a list

```
<li id="group-<%= group.id %>" class="list-group-item">
<span class="group-name"><%= group.name %></span>

<%= link_to edit_group_path(group.id), remote: true, :class => "edit-option btn" do %>
    <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o fa-2x" ></i>
<% end %>
<%= link_to group, method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Na pewno chcesz usunąć tę grupę?" }, :class => "delete-option btn btn-danger" do %>
    <i class="fa fa-trash-o" > usuń</i>
<% end %>
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Zmień nazwę grupy</h4>
            </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Anuluj</button>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a follow-up to your question of yesterday.

I won't say both your approaches are wrong, I'll say you are conbining two right approaches in such a way...

(1) since you used `js` to send save (with the use of `remote: true` on your form), all you need to do is to close the modal on successful save as will be defined from `update.js.erb` (just like you defined an `edit.js.erb` for the `format.js` in edit) as follow:

```
#update.js.erb
<% if @group.errors.empty? %>
  $('.modal-body').html("");
  $('#myModal').modal('hide');
  $("#notice").html("Group was successfully updated.");
<% else %>
  $("#notice").html("Error! Group not updated.");
<% end %>

#controller update action
def update
  @group = current_user.groups.find_by(id: params[:id])
  @group.update_attributes(group_params)
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.js
  end
end
```

What you essentially did here is to check if there is no error in the `@group` object(this will be true if @group got saved), then emptied your Modal and then hid it from view.

(2) When you removed `remote: true` you are no longer using `js`, so when you have a wrong name, the update does not work, and the `render :edit` portion of your `update` method kicks in. However, your `edit` action only specifies `format.js`, So what you may have to do in this case is to add `format.html` if you want to call with `html`.

```
def edit
 @group = current_user.groups.find_by(id: params[:id])
 respond_to do |format|
   format.js # actually means: if the client ask for js -> return file.js
   format.html
 end
end
```

Note however that this may not open your modal, it will go to the `edit_group_path` of your app, which is the `/groups/:id/edit`

Comment: Your answer for first case seems to be correct. But when I created update.js.erb nothing done. It looks like rails doesn't know that should render it. Should I change anything else, in controller or somewhere? I don't know even how to debug it correctly.

Comment: return `remote: true` to the form: `<%= form_for(@group, remote: true) do |f| %>`, and specify `format.js` in the `update` action as added  to my answer above.

Comment: I did these things. Still nothing. When I clicked "SAVE" modal is still open.

Comment: It seems that "<% if @group.errors.empty? %>" doesn't work for update.js.erb

Comment: Kindly change `$('#formModal').modal('hide');` to `$('#myModal').modal('hide');`. the `id` targeted is suppose to be the `id` of your modal. I've made the change to my answer post as well.